# How to choose the user that has sound?

Tags: debian, pulse-audio

I wanted to know if there's any way in pulseaudio to decide, each time I switch virtual terminals, if the current user should get control of the sound or if another user should keep it.

We have two users in my notebook, and (since pulseaudio is *not* in system mode) the active user is the one in control of the audio. Most of the time, that's fine. However, sometimes I am playing some music and my partner wants to use the computer and we both want to keep the music running. Is there any way to tell pulseaudio not to switch just one time? Or a reasonable way to enable/disable user switching?

I'm using debian wheezy and no user is in the audio group. I usually use mlayer as the music player.

Thanks!